# How to make ripped leather material for car seat?

Tags: rendering, materials, blender-internal-render-engine, shaders

Working on a nature scene, have  a car and since it has been exposed to nature for so long I want to make the car seats ripped a bit. Rather than looking perfectly good.
[image]
[image]
To clarify it, I am trying to achieve an old rusted car look so the even thought the car may seem a better as it is somewhat looks good , the seat does seem to be way too clean. I am not sure how to achieve something like this
[image]

Comment: Please read [this meta post](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this), have a chuckle to yourself and think about revising your question.  THanks :)

Comment: Aha thanks for clarifying. I added the thread , not sure if it is understandable now but tried my best to be clear.

Comment: Where did you get the model from? I think having the seat as base would make it easier to experiment and building the shader.